# Conveying 'on steroids'

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, science

> What is IPython? This sounds like software produced by Apple®, but it is in fact a Python interpreter on steroids.

- Qu'est-ce que IPython ? Cela ressemble à un logiciel produit par Apple®, mais il s'agit en fait d'un interprète/interpréteur  Python sous stéroïdes.
- Qu'est-ce que IPython ? Cela ressemble à un logiciel produit par Apple®, mais il s'agit en fait d'un interprète/interpréteur  Python en stéroïdes.

Je me demande si *on steroids* doit être rendu par *sous stéroïdes* ou *en steroïdes* ou une autre tournure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sous* est une préposition très courante pour exprimer une substance (souvent médicamenteuse) prise par une personne et qui agit sur son corps. Elle peut se comprendre comme "soumis à l'effet de".

Ex:

- Je suis sous antihistaminiques
- Nouvelles sous ecstasy (titre d'un livre de Beigbeder)
- Ce patient est sous oxygène

Cette préposition est donc adéquate dans l'expression "sous stéroïdes ".
"En stéroïdes" signifierait "composée de stéroïdes", qui ne correspond pas à la  même métaphore.